Deploying a react application to GitHub pages fails with error ProcessError: error: RPC failed
Deploying a react application to GitHub pages fails with error ProcessError: error: RPC failed. Detailed error is below,
ProcessError: error: RPC failed; HTTP 400 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 400
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date

    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/tinujos/Learning/tinujosk.github.io/react-app/node_modules/gh-pages/lib/git.js:42:16)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:514:28)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1105:16)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:305:5)

This happens when I do npm run deploy which calls gh-pages -d build.
Few things to keep in mind,

I can push code to the main branch without any issue, so this is not an issue with the remote repository URL.
The application is not big, it's a single-page portfolio website.

